# Parsing error(Syntax error ) occurs only on my computer. How do I fix this?

Tags: html, xml, syntax

It only occurs on a single PC.

```
Error line :
XML Parsing Error: syntax error Location: http://gall.dcinside.com/board/lists/?id=baseball_new5&page=1 Line Number 1, Column 1:

Column 1 :
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
```

Error occurring site : http://gall.dcinside.com/board/lists/?id=baseball_new5&page=1

As you can see, the document type is set as HTML while the response data is XML. Why? And how do I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The document type is XHTML, which can be taken as either traditional HTML or HTML expressed in XML format. This error could occur if your browser takes it as the latter (though I don't understand, with this message, what it doesn't like with Line 1, Column 1).

I can't reproduce this behavior, but you could snoop the exchange between the browser that shows the problem, and the website. Use your browser's Network developer tools for that.

The website probably chooses to answer to this browser, with a content-type set as application/xhtml+xml, which your browser would then parse as XML and trigger XML-related errors. It probably chooses to do so because your browser sends unconventional errors, which could be because of uncommon extensions installed or some uncommon configuration. Anyway, snoop the exchange, try to confirm or at least post what you observed.

Comment: I really appreciate your answer. Merci beaucoup, Monsieur.  You are the first person to answer to this problem.  <p>

It all started from here : http://imgur.com/a/hyTJu  <p>

I researched for a month and reached this far but I'm not a developer or  an English speaker so please understand if I act so stupid.<p>  

https://i.imgur.com/XwzYEks.png  
I'm currently at this stage. What should I do in order to snoop the problem?

Comment: You need to snoop the communication between the browser where the page gives this error instead of loading, and the website. For that, double-click the line in the Network tab where the browser fetches the page. Then look at the request and response headers. They are probably different in this browser than they are with other browsers. They will probably give some hints to investigate the problem further

Comment: You need to do that on the page that gives the error. When and where do you have the error?

Comment: It always happens when I visit the site. The thing is that it only happens on a specific computer, and on a specific site.

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/DOHoCWy.png  Here's one of red box. The red box doesn't happen often though. Would you like it more if I test this on Chrome? Thank you for your patience.

Comment: You say that the error always happen, and yet every example you give, the page is perfectly displayed right above. I ask again, *where does the error happen*? How do you know that you have this error? Where do you even read it to know that it exists in the first place? What does it prevent you to do because you would need something else instead and what is this something else?

Comment: I tried my best to explain the situation // https://i.imgur.com/j9ctebK.png  // Sorry for the poor quality. I owe you much.

Comment: The XML parsing error is not a cause of your problems, it's one of its many consequences. In that case your question is poorly asked, you should not focus on XML but on network diagnostics. It sounds like your PC's network stack doesn't like communication with this websites, possibly in its network card or its drivers, possibly because this site insists on announcing an HTTP/2 upgrade without being asked (that's not okay nor commonplace, but usually is ignored and harmless). I suggest closing this question and making a new one with this summary.

Comment: Thank you for everything. Bonne journée !